# How many Watt Hours are consumed to jumpstart car?

Tags: battery, starting, chevrolet, camshaft

I bought one of these [portable jump starters](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00VIN920M). This one says in specification that it can start a big 6L gasoline engine up to 12 times on a single charge. Simple math implies that each jump-start attempt should consume 100%/12=8.5%. At least for big engines.

Now I am using it to jumpstart Chevrolet Aveo with a smaller 1.6L engine. I have tried to jump start my car with it like 10 times for 3-4 seconds each time and the portable jumpstarter's charge status has barely dropped from 74% to 72%.

**This has left me wondering on how many WHr typically are needed to jump start a small 1.6L engine?**

**While I see that starter spins the belt in my car, is there a chance that actual load (e.g. camshaft) is somehow not connected to the belt and hence the charge on the portable jump starter drops by insignificant amount? By the way I am not able to start the car and I am also getting code "P0340: Camshaft position sensor error". See this [question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/48195/chevrolet-aveo-does-wont-start-codes-p0340-p2106-p2110-p2101) for more context.**

Comment: For your car assume 12v and 400A, that gives power , multipy by time 3 to 4 seconds , convert seconds to hours and you have your answer in Wh...

Comment: 12V*400A/3600seconds*3seconds=4Whr/attempt. 10 attempts would be 40whr. However, my portable jumpstarter lost 2% charge during these 10 jumpstart attempts. So the total capacity of  that portable jump starter would have to be 40*(100/2)=2000Whr which is way above the claimed jumpstarter capacity of ~14whr. I guess it could be that the lead-acid battery is still doing the job then. Or 400A is peak power and does not remain constant during these 3 seconds.

Comment: No the current draw is not constant - electric motors create back emf ... And your battery will most probably be helping as you mention unless it is completely dead or broken

Comment: another thing going on here is the meter claiming 2% discharge on that unit is likely not at all accurate.