# Non-zero voltage on camshaft position sensor power wire without main relay. Is there short somewhere?

Tags: electrical, chevrolet, wiring, camshaft, short

I have been troubleshooting Camshaft Position Sensor no-start issue in [this thread](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/48195/chevrolet-aveo-wont-start-codes-p0340-p2106-p2110-p2101/48197?noredirect=1#comment84410_48197) for my 2007 Chevrolet Aveo. Long story short - in one of the answers it was suspected that camshaft position sensor is not getting stable 12V, so as a test it was suggested to connect Battery+ directly to the sensor's camshaft position sensor's Orange pin and car started successfully. Now, it surprisingly also starts without connecting the Orange pin directly to the Battery+ anymore.

However, I want to root cause this issue properly so that it does not happen again while I am driving.

Today I did a test where I measured voltage on Sensor Harness'es Orange wire with and without "main relay" plugged in when key was in "ON", position:

[image: Without main relay]

[image: With main relay]

As can be seen the voltage without relay is 2.4V, which I think is wrong. It should have been 0V. **My questions are**:

1. Based on this test, can I conclude that "main relay" most likely is actually OK?
2. Since I see 2.4V without main relay, then does it mean that there are two power wires with different voltages shorted together after the main relay?
3. If so, then can that information of knowing 2.4V can be used to pinpoint the other wire that is shorted with the Orange wire?
4. The obvious way to me seems to open all the splices in the fusebox after "main relay" power wire and see from which wire the 2.4V are coming and then just keep going forward until wire with 2.4V is isolated. Of course I would need to restore splices to the original condition after that. Any other better tips on how should I approach this problem?

P.S. May or may not be related - I have red Airbag light on for more than a year. Chevrolet dealership did not know how to root cause, because there "were no SRS codes". Could it be that AirBag is using 2.4V and has shorted somewhere with Camshaft position sensor power wire hence both issues?  Though the timing does not match when both issues started to manifest themselves.

**Update#1**: I added load (resistor and yellow LED light) between sensor harness'es orange wire and Battery -. Voltage dropped from 2.4V to 1.98V, and the LED did light up (the alligator wire from battery- to the breadboard changes color to white and is not captured in the picture):

[image: Not stray voltage]

**Update#2**: Voltage measurements when key was in "ON" position ("Voltage between Battery Minus and" column should be correct. However, in "Voltage between Orange and" I may need to redo some measurement, because I think somewhere there I should see 0.4V and 10.1V):

[image]

If my interpretation is correct, then here is how last test with both fuses and relay removed looked like. Since there was continuity only between EMS1(R) and EMS2(L) then I assumed that those pins must be the ones facing Main relay.

[image]

I guess what this test suggests is that EMS1(L) and EMS2(R) and something else with voltage >2.4V is shorted together? Also, there was 109KOhm resistance between EMS1(L) and EMS2(R).

**Update#3**

With the battery disconnected the 107KOhm resistance between EMS1 and EMS2 changed to infinity once I unplugged the upper cable to PCM as well:

[image]

Also, with key in ON position and Main relay, EMS1 fuse and EMS2 fuse unplugged I got following voltage measurement between Battery Minus and CMP Orange wire:

1. Upper cable and lower cable to PCM plugged in - 2.4V
2. Upper cable to PCM plugged and lower unplugged - 11.81V
3. Upper cable and  lower cable to PCM unplugged - 0V.

So my latest 2 questions are:

**Does this mean that PCM is malfunctioning and it is the reason why I see those 2.4V on CMP Orange wire even with EMS2 fuse removed? Or there is still possibility of something else causing that 2.4V on Orange sensor wire (e.g. after unplugging PCM the hypothetical 3rd circuit was not getting power hence it could not cause voltage leak on EMS2 circuit)?**

**Why with lower cable to PCM unplugged, but upper one plugged, I suddenly start to see 11.81V instead of 2.4V or 0V?**

[image]

**Update#4**: With the key in "OFF" position and both PCM cables unplugged I connected Battery Plus directly to EMS1 terminal (that is facing harness, not main relay) and then measured voltage between Battery Minus and EMS2 fuse terminal that is also facing harness. As can be seen the voltage is 0V which I believe proves that there is no **direct** leak between EMS1 circuit and EMS2 circuit.

[image]

**Errata**:

- In the past I incorrectly called CMP's "Orange" wire as "Pink" wire. It is actually Orange for my notchback model and presumably Pink for hetchback model.

Comment: Perhaps you want to draw this point to ground with a temporary 1KOhm resistance and measure again?

Comment: Attention: do not allow shorts, as the car battery has dangerously much current.

Comment: @Myself you mean to rule out possibility that 2.4V that I see without main relay is stray voltage? I added picture that IMHO demonstrates that it is not stray voltage.

Comment: Try pulling the EMS 1 fuse to see if the voltage is bleeding in from another circuit. The Main relay powers both the EMS 1 and 2 fuses. Maybe try unplugging the PCM as well. I'd probably pull the EMS 1 fuse and unplug everything on the EMS 2 circuit and see if the voltage is still there. That way you know it's not a shorted component and it's a wiring issue.

Comment: @Ben In Update#2 I added table of Voltage measurements with both Fuses and Relays in all possible states (i.e. Present or Absent). I added the third column "Voltage between Pink and" for redundancy. I hope I did not make any mistakes. I think that last row with both Fuses and Relay removed indicate that leakage is coming from another circuit?

Comment: This is a great question. Favorited for later perusal

Comment: @Ben forgot to do other thing you asked... I guess what you meant was to unplug other sensors and PCM one by one and to monitor voltage on Orange wire? Is it OK to unplug them while car is ON? Or could I rather simply monitor resistance between EMS1(L) and EMS2(R) and see if by unplugging something it goes from 109KOhms to infinity while car is OFF?

Comment: Sensors you can unplug with the key on the PCM you should do key off. I would unplug everything on the circuit look for a good reading then plug them in one at a time. Either way would work I'm just thinking it may be easier having a clean disconnect from all the components on the circuit. Hmm... can you take a reading at the G104 ground in the diagram as well?

Comment: I'm thinking the reason you see 109kΩ between the two circuits is that both share a common ground point at G104. It COULD be a short but It'd be nice to eliminate the ground as a false flag. Unplugging the components probably would yield the same results as unbolting the ground.

Comment: @Ben The voltage between Battery Minus and G104 was 0V. Hence I think that electricity was not "flowing up" from a different circuit to EMS2 circuit towards fuses. However, after unplugging one of the cables from PCM the voltage between CMP Orange wire and Battery Minus changed from 2.4V to 11.81V. After I unplugged second cable this voltage changed to 0V. See update#3 where I tried to capture in pictures what I did. Does this mean I need new PCM? Is there explanation on why I started to see 11.81V on CMP orange wire? Thanks again for all your guidance in this!

Comment: With both PCM connectors unplugged can you plug the cmp sensor back in, jump B+ to one of the EMS fuse (harness side) terminals and take measurements on the other?

Comment: @Ben See Update#4. The voltage I got was 0V. I suppose it proves that there is no direct short between EMS1 and EMS2 circuits and that there must be a third circuit bridging both of them together? Presumably this third circuit is in PCM; But another unlikely possibility could be that it is external circuit where EMS1 and EMS2 have shorted at different location and between them is a switch/relay preventing electricity leakage. Since I had key in OFF position that hypothetical switch may have been shut off. Though I find this unlikely.

Comment: I would check it with the key on as well. I’d still be hesitant to call it a pcm without a known good circuit to test against. If I run into an aveo with similar specs i’ll run a few tests. In the meanwhile I’d suggest you clean any engine to frame and the g104 grounds. And swap out the main relay. I’ll see if I can post an answer that makes sense later on. Check for any corrosion in the under side of the fuse box and maybe spray some contact cleaner in there.

Comment: @Ben, could it be that those 2.4V are expected to be there with fuses removed (e.g. PCM via pull-up resistor provides electricity? One person from Chevy Aveo forum suggested this theory and I see that there is connectivity from one of the PCM slot pins to the EMS2 branch). Though I am not sure why GM would have designed such circuit except to monitor voltage? [http://www.aveoforum.com/forum/f82/expected-see-2-4v-ems2-circuit-even-ems2-fuse-removed-22563/#post204998]

Comment: it's certainly possible. Another thought I had was a bad low reference/floating ground, but I couldn't square it against the data and didn't mention it. I believe I've seen similar readings on a low reference circuit before, but I can't remember what the circuit was or what the complaint was. Maybe someone on the Aveo forums would be willing to take some readings.

Answer (score 1):

i'm really surprised! you have really a good knowledge in diagnostic techniques,
any way upon to my experience that car has faulty ecm motherboard , you have to make sure in case if you disconnect the ecm you will loss " ROM" the keep alive memory or not because the same thing with camaro , if not you can disconnect ecm and see voltage will drop to zero at orange terminal camshaft with main relay pluged , if yes >>>replace ecm , if no >>>>replace harness